# How to store images for Tensorflow and Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I have about 100,000 images of 10 classes. Reading these image everytime is a time consuming.I want to store these image as CIFAR10 or any other dataset so I can read them quickly and fit them into models easily.

Comment: Hi. Could you show your code so someone can help you to improve it?

Answer (score 2):

You can convert images into binary format which is understandable by tensorflow called "tfrecord" format.

Please refer to the below links

https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets
http://www.machinelearninguru.com/deep_learning/tensorflow/basics/tfrecord/tfrecord.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply, is this the way that CIFAR data is stored?

Comment: Cifar10 is stored in multiple batch files, not in tfrecord format by default.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of doing it.

You can store images in ten folders with class names as their name, You can store ten numpy arrays (`numpy.save()` and `numpy.load()`) containing images for each class. You can store one numpy array containing all of your images. You can use tfrecords which is mentioned by @Rajeswari

fastest option is tfrecords tfrecord file, it can also be saved and read as multiple shards which helps if you don't have enough memory to hold all of the data in memory at once, worst option is keeping them as image files. Saving a  numpy array is easier than creating tfrecords while still being fast.